# Server Sent Events (SSE) with nghttp2

Tags: c++, c, server-sent-events

Is it possible to create/submit server sent events using the nghttp2-Library.

Up to now, we haven't beeen successful writing a sample server application , that responds to a 'subscription' with periodic SSEs. We have used the current Version 1.56.0-DEV of the bghttp2 library.

As the documentation does not contain any description/example about SSE, we are wondering, if SSEs are supported from the lib.

We are expecting information, if it is possbile to use the nghttp2 lib for SSE ? If yes, wany hint to existing documentation/ code samples would be appreciated.